# Use dagger2 with Retrofit and MVVM

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-2

I'm trying to use `Dagger`, `Retrofit`, and `VMMV` structure in my app, but I don't know how to use `Retrofit` in this case. I have my Module and Interface where i realize my calls to the `API`. I use `Dagger` before and i think i should have a component to connect my `ApiCalls` with my `MainViewModel` where i want to use it. I'm in the correct way? If not how i should make the bind with my `ViewModel` to get the `Observable` with the credentials?

My `NetworkModule`:

```
@Module
object NetworkModule{

    /**
     * Provides the Post service implementation.
     * @param retrofit the Retrofit object used to instantiate the service
     * @return the Post service implementation.
     */
    @Provides
    @Reusable
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideUserAuth(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiCredentials{
        return retrofit.create(ApiCredentials::class.java)
    }

    /**
     * Provides the Retrofit object.
     * @return the Retrofit object
     */
    val provideRetrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}
```

My `ApiCalls` with Retrofit:

```
interface ApiCredentials {

    @get:POST("/api/auth/sign_in")
    val getAuthentication: Observable<Credentials>
}
```

My `MainViewModel`:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // TODO: Implement the ViewModel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make repository where in constructor you can get refrence of your interface and via a method you can hit api in repo.

```
class ApiRepository @Inject constructor(
private val apiCredentials: ApiCredentials
) {
 fun hitApi():Observable<Credentials>{
 return apiCredentials.getAuthentication
 }
}
```

In view model you can get object of this repo via injector like

```
@Inject
protected lateinit var repo: ApiRepository
```

and in view model you can use this.

Comment: You don't answer my question. How i can bind the `ApiCalls` and `ViewModel` through the `Module` and the `Component`?